# Convert .txt into .csv when some rows have missing data for certain columns (python)

Tags: python, csv

I have a `.txt` file that is currently formatted kind of like this:

```
John,bread,17,www.google.com
Emily,apples,24,
Anita,35,www.website.com
Charles,banana,www.stackoverflow.com
Susie,french fries,31,www.regexr.com
...
```

The first column will never have any missing values.

I'm trying to use python to convert this into a `.csv` file. I know how to do this if I have all of the column data for each row, but my `.txt` is missing some data in certain columns. How can I convert this to a `.csv` while making sure the same type of data remains in the same column? Thanks :)

Comment: Open the file, split by `\n` or `\r\n`, then split each line by `,`. You then have a list that contains each value, and you can manually process it to do whatever you want.

Comment: basically you're asking how to identify when there's missing data in each row, and add an empty cell in the csv like this: `Anita,,35,www.website.com`?

Comment: @Aaron yeah something like that

Comment: can the first column have missing values? are data types of each column known beforehand, etc...

Comment: @aws_apprentice The first column does not have any missing values. idk about data types but each thing in the 4th column is a URL, each thing in the 3rd column is an integer value etc.

Answer (score 1):

Split by commas. You know the pattern should be word, word, int(I'm assuming), string in the pattern of www.word.word.

1. If there is only 1 word at the front instead of 2, add another comma after the first word.
2. If the number is missing, add a comma after the second word.
3. Etc...

Say you get a line "Susie,www.regexr.com" , you know that there is a missing word and missing number. Add 2 commas after the first word.

It's essentially a bunch of if statements or a switch-case statement.

There probably is a more elegant way of doing this, but my mind is fried from dealing with server and phone issues all morning.

This **isn't** tested in any way, I hope I didn't just embarrass myself:

```
    import re

    #read_line is a line read from the csv
    split_line = read_line.split(',')
    num_elements = len(split_line) #do this only once for efficiency
    if (num_elements == 3): #Need to add an element somewhere, depending on what's missing
        if(re.search('[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+',split_line[2])): #Starting at the last element, if it is an email address
            if(re.search('[\d]',split_line[1])): #If the previous element is a digit
                #if so, add a comma as the only element missing is the string at split_line[1]
                read_line = split_line[0]+','+','+split_line[1]+','+split_line[2]
            else:
                #if not so, add a comma at split_line[2]
                read_line = split_line[0]+','+split_line[1]+','+','+split_line[2]
        else:
            #last element isn't email address, add a comma in its place
            read_line = split_line[0]+','+split_line[1]+','+split_line[2]+','

    elif (num_elements == 2) #need two elements, first one is assumed to always be there
        if(re.search('[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+',split_line[1])): #The second element is an email address
            #Insert 2 commas in for missing string and number
            read_line = split_line[0]+',,,'+split_line[1]
        elif(re.search('[\d]',split_line[1])): #The second element contains digits
            #Insert commas for missing string and email address
            read_line = split_line[0]+',,'+split_line[1]+','
        else:
            #Insert commas for missing number and email address
            read_line = split_line[0]+','+split_line[1]+',,'
    elif (num_elements == 1):
        read_line = split_line[0]+',,,'
```

Comment: To help with the question below, you can use back references (https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to do this. just back reference the digit and then replace it with the value of the number with an added comma in front of it.

Comment: I've put some code I sketched out for him, but he should be able to go with a general description of a solution as I suggested. I don't mind putting out the code on request, but I also don't want to do someone's homework for them. Being down voted by a bunch of people isn't really encouraging people to help out, though. I think I might avoid submitting to SO after the down votes :-(.

Comment: thanks for the help! i'll try this out. also this isn't for homework, its for my co-op work placement haha.

Comment: Thank you Seshie. I apologize for the tone of my comment. I've had a lot of stress and anxiety from several major projects that I'm in charge of at work and it's getting to me. It kind of came out in my post. Good luck with your placement and let me know if there is anything I can help with! *edit*: The email regex might or might not be correct, I just googled it. I've found this as well:

Comment: The email regex might or might not be correct, I just googled it. I've found this as well: re.match("^.+@([?)[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$", email) . Regex has never been my strong point.

Comment: @Andy fair enough to not do someone's homework. Commenting can give tips. However if you offer an answer, you ll have accept people's scrutiny. goodwill is great but learning the rules help a lot too. Cheers.

Comment: part of posting a complete answer is testing it as well, and you're not being downvoted because we don't want you to help, you're being downvoted because you're not following the community rules

Answer (score 0):

I thought about your issue and I can only offer a half baked solution as your CSV file, when having missing data do not show it with something like `,,`.

Your current csv file is like that

```
John,bread,17,www.google.com
Emily,apples,24,
Anita,35,www.website.com
Charles,banana,www.stackoverflow.com
Susie,french fries,31,www.regexr.com
```

If you find a way to change your CSV file to like that

```
John,bread,17,www.google.com
Emily,apples,24,
Anita,,35,www.website.com
Charles,banana,,www.stackoverflow.com
Susie,french fries,31,www.regexr.com
```

You can use the solution like below. For info, I've put your input into a text file

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd   
In [2]: population = pd.read_csv('input_to_csv.txt')
In [3]: mod_population=population.fillna("NaN")
In [4]: mod_population.to_csv('output_to_csv.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

One suggestion would be to do a regex check, if you can assume some kind of uniformity.  For example, build a list of regex patterns, since each piece of data seems to be different.

If the second column you read in matches all characters and spaces, it's likely food.  On the other hand, if it's a digit match, you should assume that food is missing.  If it's a url match, you missed both.  You'll want to be thorough with your test cases, but if the actual data is similar to your example you have 3 relatively unique cases, with a string, an integer, and a url.  This should make writing regex tasks relatively trivial. Importing re and using re.search should help you test each regex without too much overhead.

Comment: If I'm using regex, how do I assign the data to a certain column? eg. if I find out that the second column is a digit match, what would I write to make it so the 2nd column in my csv is blank and the 3rd column has the digit? Thanks

Comment: Build a string, if you need to, and fill it in as "%s,%s,%s,%s" %(name, food, id, website).  Fill those variables with what you find, defaulting a blank string, and then write out to a file.